# python reference to a float, int, etc

Tags: python, reference

As I understand it, there are no references in python to `int`s or `float`s or similar data.  Nevertheless, I am working on a problem where it would be very convenient for me if I could do something like

```
a=1
b=2
c=3
ref_dict={'field1':ref_to_var_a,'field2':ref_to_var_b,'field3':ref_to_var_c}
```

and then

```
def update(field,value):
   ref_dict[field]=value
```

And so if the user called

```
update('field2',5)
```

the value of `b` would become 5.

Is there any way this can be done?  Thanks.

In response to arbanert's helpful comment and answer, what I really want to do is -- surprise, surprise -- more complicated.  I am building a GUI with wxPython.  I have many TextCtrl controls, each of which will set the value of one variable.  Of course, I could write one method for each control, or I could write a single method, which would look something like

```
def handleTextEvent(self,event):
    if (event.GetEventObject() == widget1):
       a=int(event.GetString)
    elif (event.GetEventObject() == widget2):
       b= ....
```

I think you can see why I don't like this either.  It would be nice if I could just do one short function like:

```
def handleTextEvent(self,event):
    ref_dict[event.GetEventObject()]=int(event.GetString())
```

And, yes, I am very new with wxPython.

Thanks!

Comment: If you showed why this would be convenient, it would be easier to answer—because the answer is probably "you don't really want to do that".

Comment: The point is to force you to start with reasonable data structures - if you really want to write this code it will look like `structure.update('field', 5)`

Comment: @JochenRitzel: +1. But just `structure.field = 5` is even better most of the time…

Comment: What about the `update` method for dictionaries?  Can you create one from the key and new value and call that?

Comment: In response to your update: This is standard MVC (or MTL or whatever). Your `TextCtrl`s are part of a GUI view. The corresponding model should be represented as an object, not as a bunch of scattered globals. Just store a reference to that object in the view (or its controller), and `handleTextEvent` can just set attributes on it.

Comment: Maybe a quick workaround: use lists of length one instead of numbers. This will allow you to reference.

Comment: @arbanert: Much obliged for your help.  Hope you don't mind me being still confused.  The numbers I want to control are part of a model, i.e. an object.  I listed them as global here just to keep things simple.  My problem is that, even though they are in an object, I can't figure out how to reference each of them, except for with the two very long alternatives I mentioned in my question.  Found a site on MVC with WxPython and it was pretty opaque and didn't have an example of what I hope I can do.  Muchos gracias once again.

Comment: @bob.sacamento: I'm not sure what the `'field1'`, `'field2'`, etc. names are supposed to represent here. If they're part of the model, you probably want a `model.set_field('field1')` (or `model.set_field(1)`), and inside the model object it does `setattr(self, name_mapping_dict[field])`. If they're part of the view… why not just store the names `'a'`, `'b'`, etc. in the view? Then it's `setattr(self.model, field, value)`.

Comment: @bob.sacamento: However, if you're normally accessing these attributes dynamically by name, and only occasionally using normal attribute access, you probably just want to stick them in a `dict` as part of the public interface of the model, so it's just `self.model.thingies[field] = value`.

Comment: @arbanert:  As I continue to think about it, I think I was in over my head as soon as you said, "TextCtrls are part of a GUI view."  Like I said, I am new to wxPython and I haven't tried to do any GUI stuff in years.  Could you point me to a reference on what you mean?  As for the "field1" etc., I was just using those strings as an example.  What I thought I would like to do is use the actual widgets as keys in the dictionary I was hoping to build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This *is* possible, but it's almost always a bad idea.

Assuming `a`, `b`, and `c` are globals:

```
ref_dict = {'field1': 'a', 'field2': 'b', 'field3': 'c'}
def update(field, value):
    globals()[ref_dict[field]] = value
```

---

If you *really* want to, you can even create "reference wrappers":

```
class GlobalReference(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def get(self):
        return globals()[self.name]
    def set(self, value):
        globals()[self.name] = value

ref_dict = {'field1': GlobalReference('a'), 'field2': GlobalReference('b')}
def update(field, value):
    ref_dict[field].set(value)
```

And if you want to wrap things that aren't in `globals`, like globals from another module, class attributes, instance attributes, etc.? Create more reference wrapper types:

```
class NamespaceReference(object):
    def __init__(self, namespace, name):
        self.namespace, self.name = namespace, name
    def get(self):
        return getattr(self.namespace, self.name)
    def set(self, value):
        setattr(self.namespace, self.name, value)

ref_dict = {'field1': GlobalReference('a'), 'field2': NamespaceReference('myobj', 'b')}
```

Or you can forgo the classes and just store setter functions…

---

So, if this is a bad idea, what's the right answer?

Without knowing what you're trying to do, it's hard to say, but here are some possibilities:

- Use a single `dict` variable full of values instead of a bunch of separate variables.
- Make the variables instance attributes of a class, and pass an instance of that class around.
- Use a mutable float-holder object instead of a plain float instance.

---

For your specific case, I think what you want is the second one. This is standard model-view-controller design. Or, if you don't like MVC, model-template-view or some other variant (you don't really need a controller here).

Your model is a bunch of scattered globals, which is why it's hard to hook it up to the view. The simplest answer is to represent the model as an object. Then give the view (or its controller) a reference to this model, which is trivial, and you're done.

Comment: But, this *only* works if `a`, `b` etc. are defined in the same module as `update`, so it still isn't true reference manipulation.

Comment: @mgilson: If they're globals in another module, you do `setattr(other_module, ref_dict[field], value)`. And you can do similar things for class attributes, instance attributes, etc. You can even wrap these things up with simple GlobalReference, LocalReference, NamespaceReference, etc. classes and pass those around.